# Days till year end

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I need to find the numbers of days left from today till the end of the year. I know I can calculate this by simply subtracting today's date from the December 31st of this year, ie:

```
current_year = dt.datetime.now().year
days_left = dt.date(current_year, 12, 31) - dt.datetime.now().date()
```

Is there a smarter/faster way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Seems fine to me.

Comment: It works, but I would expect there to be something more efficient, like the pandas DateOffset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this a little more concise:

```
import datetime as dt
from timeit import timeit

def v1():
    today = dt.date.today()
    end_of_year = dt.date(today.year, 12, 31)
    return (end_of_year - today).days

def v2():
    current_year = dt.datetime.now().year
    days_left = dt.date(current_year, 12, 31) - dt.datetime.now().date()
    return days_left.days

for func in v1, v2:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(func))
```

**Output:**

```
v1 0.919826476999333
v2 1.319277847000194
```

Comment: Thanks! I do like this a bit better than my own solution